# Creating sequence of descending and ascending values in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sequence, repeat

I'm pretty new in R, trying to create a dataframe with several factors, one of them ("probability") needs to consist of a sequence of ascending values (30, 40, 50, 60, 70) 25 times, followed by a sequence of descending values (70, 60, 50, 50, 30) for 25 times.

here's what i have tried so far:

```
probability = c(seq(30, 70, 10, along_with=1:25), rev(seq(30, 70, 10, along_with=1:25))),
probability = rep(c(c(30, 40, 50, 60, 70), len=25), rep(c(70, 60, 50, 40, 30), len=25)),
probability = rep(c(c(30, 40, 50, 60, 70), c(70, 60, 50, 40, 30), each=25)),
```

I would appreciate any help from you guys...

Thanks!

Comment: Looks cool, what is your problem with it?

Comment: all i managed to get was sequences of 30x25, 40x25, 50x25 etc.. or errors. i need 25 sequences of 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, and then 25 sequences of 70, 60, 50, 40, 30....

Comment: is `rep(c(c(30, 40, 50, 60, 70), c(70, 60, 50, 40, 30)), each=25)` what you want ? parenthesis problem in your code

Comment: I don't understand, is this `rep(c(seq(30, 70, 10), seq(70, 30, -10)), 25)` it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
probability_ascending<-rep(c(30, 40, 50, 60, 70),25)
probability_descending<-rep(c(70, 60, 50, 40, 30),25)
```

If you want it in one vector:

```
probability<-c(rep(c(30, 40, 50, 60, 70),25),rep(c(70, 60, 50, 40, 30),25))
```

Comment: Hi all, first of all, thanks a lot for your willingness to help :-)

sorry if I wasn't clear enough.. I needed the following sequence: 
30 40 50 60 70 30 40 50 60 70 30 40 50 60 70 etc ... each sequence for 5 times, or all the numbers for 25 times. then 70 60 50 40 30 70 60 50 40 30 etc...each sequence for 5 times, or all the numbers for 25 times. 

I took some of what you suggested and changed it a little bit, and it worked!

    probability = c(rep(c(30, 40, 50, 60, 70),5),rep(c(70, 60, 50, 40, 30),5)),

THANKS!

Comment: That's what I thought you needed. If you have found the answer helpful, then you can consider upvoting or accepting it

Answer (score 1):

There where a problem in parenthesis, adding a wrong element 25 in your last line.

You can do: `rep(c(seq(30, 70, 10), seq(70, 30, -10)), each = 25)`

Comment: I think OP wants 30,40,50,60,70 repeated 25 times in the sequence followed by 70,60,50,40,30 repeated 25 times in sequence

Comment: Yes exactly what it does

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step by step answer to get at my comment to the question.

**1.** These are the sequences to be repeated.

```r
# first sequence
seq(30, 70, 10)
#> [1] 30 40 50 60 70

# second sequence
seq(70, 30, -10)
#> [1] 70 60 50 40 30
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**2.** Combine them into one vector.

```r
# combine the sequences above
c(seq(30, 70, 10), seq(70, 30, -10))
#>  [1] 30 40 50 60 70 70 60 50 40 30
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**3.** Repeat the result above 25 times.

```r
# combine the sequences above
rep(c(seq(30, 70, 10), seq(70, 30, -10)), 25)
#>   [1] 30 40 50 60 70 70 60 50 40 30
#>  [11] 30 40 50 60 70 70 60 50 40 30
#>  [21] 30 40 50 60 70 70 60 50 40 30
#>  [31] 30 40 50 60 70 70 60 50 40 30
#>  [41] 30 40 50 60 70 70 60 50 40 30
#>  [51] 30 40 50 60 70 70 60 50 40 30
#>  [61] 30 40 50 60 70 70 60 50 40 30
#>  [71] 30 40 50 60 70 70 60 50 40 30
#>  [81] 30 40 50 60 70 70 60 50 40 30
#>  [91] 30 40 50 60 70 70 60 50 40 30
#> [101] 30 40 50 60 70 70 60 50 40 30
#> [111] 30 40 50 60 70 70 60 50 40 30
#> [121] 30 40 50 60 70 70 60 50 40 30
#> [131] 30 40 50 60 70 70 60 50 40 30
#> [141] 30 40 50 60 70 70 60 50 40 30
#> [151] 30 40 50 60 70 70 60 50 40 30
#> [161] 30 40 50 60 70 70 60 50 40 30
#> [171] 30 40 50 60 70 70 60 50 40 30
#> [181] 30 40 50 60 70 70 60 50 40 30
#> [191] 30 40 50 60 70 70 60 50 40 30
#> [201] 30 40 50 60 70 70 60 50 40 30
#> [211] 30 40 50 60 70 70 60 50 40 30
#> [221] 30 40 50 60 70 70 60 50 40 30
#> [231] 30 40 50 60 70 70 60 50 40 30
#> [241] 30 40 50 60 70 70 60 50 40 30
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>